# Angular JS ui-tinymce

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-directive

I use ui-tinymce module in angular project. In one controller are called `tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'ntContent');` and this works fine. But after grunt build command I get the following error: `ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined`. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: It sounds like the tinymce javascript dependency isn't included. It can't fine the 'tinymce' variable declared anywhere. Check to make sure the tinymce javascript file is being loaded before all your angular code is run.

Comment: try including directly with cdn <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 in your page head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with **angular-ui-tinymce** module, I fixed this by making sure that the file is included.

```
<script src="bower_components/tinymce-dist/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js"></script>
```

This scripts are inserted in the index.html file `bower install angular-ui-tinymce` and also the source code is downloaded and placed at the appropriate location.

Also when you run `grunt build` on the copy task it will not copy the files needed from the `/tinymce-dist`folder and a solution is to manually add to the **copy task** to copy the folders you need. I had to copy the `/skins` `/themes` `/plugins` folders directly into the `dist/scripts` folder by inserting the following code into the grunt.js file at the copy task:

```
// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          ...
        }, {
          ...
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/tinymce-dist/themes/modern/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/themes/modern/'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/tinymce-dist/skins/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/skins/'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/tinymce-dist/plugins/link/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/plugins/link/'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        ...
      }
    }
```

This is not the best solution ever but it worked for me, hope it helps somebody.